# WiFi connected but not working

Tags: drivers, wireless

[Details from lspci command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QqUP.png). So I recently changed from windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04, and I encountered an issue with the WiFi connection. It connects fine when logging on, but about 5 minutes the connection still shows there is WiFi, but it isn't actually working. When I select WiFi, and select network, no networks are found. I have seen other people with similar issues but no apparent fix has been found, so I decided to upgrade to version 18.10. I thought it was fine, but the same problem occurs, except in wifi settings it says "connected" and shows my WiFi. It doesn't load any pages on Google just like 18.04, so I'm assuming it's my PC. Could someone please help me as I may just have to return to windows. (A similar thing happened on windows, where the WiFi would stop working and no connection s could be found but would start working again after about 2 minutes). Someone please help. I may have drivers missing or something as wired connection works absolutely fine

Comment: Dear, friend need more info about your hardware :) wifi adapter or notebook model. You may get it with command lspci

Comment: @Terentev Maksim I did that now.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem with 16.04 overview here, maybe it help you
https://www.google.com/amp/s/codeyarns.com/2017/02/04/how-to-make-intel-wireless-ac-3165-work-in-ubuntu/amp/

Comment: I couldn't really follow along because I'm using 18.10 and they using 16.04 LTS